# how to fill select dropdown from mysql in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, mysql, select, jqgrid, dropdown

**> Hello, I'm a beginner developer.

> When selecting 'largeCategoryZone', separate it with ASCIICode to
> retrieve the value from db.
>
> I'd like to put those values in the 'smallCategoryZone'. The content
> below is my code. Please check and Please answer me.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#AdminCheckJqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "../barcode/barcodeAdminCheckInquiry/1",
        datatype: "json",
        loadtext: "loading...",
        method: "GET",
        postData: {
            "certificateNumber": $("#certificateNumber").val()
        },
        colNames: ['sku', 'label', 'qty', 'realQty', 'palletType', 'palletBarcode','largeCategoryZone','middleCategoryZone','smallCategoryZone', 'remark'],
        colModel: [
            {label: 'sku', name: 'sku', width: '30', align: 'center'},
            {label: 'label', name: 'label', width: '60', align: 'center'},
            {label: 'qty', name: 'qty', width: '20', align: 'center'},
            {label: 'realQty', name: 'realQty', width: 30,align: 'center', sortable: false, editable: true},
            {label: 'palletType', name: 'palletType', width: 40, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {dataUrl: '../code/palletType', buildSelect: setSelect}},
            {label: 'palletBarcode', name: 'palletBarcode', width: 40, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {dataUrl: '../code/palletBarcode', buildSelect: palletBarcodeSelect}},
            {label: 'largeCategoryZone', name: 'largeCategoryZone', width: 40, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {dataUrl: '../code/largeCategoryZone', buildSelect:setSelect ,
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            var selectedData = e.currentTarget.value;
                            var dataFrist = selectedData.substr(0,1);
                            var dataAscii = dataFrist.charCodeAt();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '../code/largeCategoryZone/' + dataAscii,
                                type: 'GET',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var jdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data).result;
                                    var selectHtml = "";

                                    for(var i=0; i < jdata.length; i++){
                                        selectHtml += "<option value='" + jdata[i].subcode + "'>" + jdata[i].codename + "</option>";
                                    }

                                    if ($(e.target).is('.FormElement')) {
                                        var form = $(e.target).closest('form.FormGrid');
                                        console.log("form"+form);
                                        $("select#smallCategoryZone.FormElement", form[0]).html(selectHtml);
                                    } else {
                                        var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                        var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                        var rowId = jQuery("#AdminCheckJqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                                        jQuery("select#" + rowId + "_smallCategoryZone").append(selectHtml);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }}]}},
            {label: 'middleCategoryZone', name: 'middleCategoryZone', width: 40, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {dataUrl: '../code/largeCategoryZone', buildSelect: setSelect}},
            {label: 'smallCategoryZone', name: 'smallCategoryZone', width: 40, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select',editoptions: {  } },
            {label: 'remark', name: 'remark', width: 50, sortable: false, editable: true, align: 'center', editoptions: {autocomplete: "off"}},
        ],
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your problem with this code?

Comment: smallCategoryZone is not filled @TonyTomov

Answer (score 1):

I solved dropDown with setCell

> var check =
> $("#moveZoneJqGrid").jqGrid("setCell",rowid,"moveToBarcode",selectHtml);

```
   {label: 'moveToThird', name: 'smallCategoryZone', width: 25, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select',editoptions: {
                      dataEvents: [{
                                     type: 'change',
                                     fn: function(e) {
                                        var rowid =  e.originalEvent.path[2].id;
                                        var rowval = $('#moveZoneJqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
                                        var jdata = new Object();
    
                                        var largeCategoryZone = rowval.largeCategoryZone;
                                        var middleCategoryZone = rowval.middleCategoryZone;
                                        var smallCategoryZone = e.currentTarget.value;
    
                                         $.ajax({
                                             url: "../barcode/getBarcodeFromZone",
                                             method: "GET",
                                             data : {
                                                 "largeCategoryZone" : largeCategoryZone,
                                                 "middleCategoryZone" : middleCategoryZone,
                                                 "smallCategoryZone" : smallCategoryZone,
                                             },
                                             dataType: "json",
                                             success: function (data) {
                                                 var jdata = data.inquiryList
                                                 var selectHtml = "<select>";
    
                                                 for(var i=0; i < jdata.length; i++){
                                                    selectHtml += '<option value="' + jdata[i].barcode + '">' + jdata[i].barcode + '</option>';
                                                 }
                                                   selectHtml += "</select>";
    
                                                   var check = $("#moveZoneJqGrid").jqGrid("setCell",rowid,"moveToBarcode",selectHtml);
    
                                             },
                                             error: function(xhr, status, err){
                                                 alert(status + "\n" + err);
                                             }
                                         }); //ajax
                                     } //fn function
                                 }] // dataEvent
                            } //editoption
                    },
                {label: 'moveToBarcode', name: 'moveToBarcode', width: '35', align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { }},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine with last version of Guriddo jqGrid.
You will need to fine up your code.

First  you will need to set a default value for smallCategoryZone when define the select in colModel

```
{label: 'smallCategoryZone', name: 'smallCategoryZone', width: 40, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'select',editoptions: { value:":SelectCity" } },
```

Second: when calling ajax you will need to check that the data is here and use html instead of append for the inline edit the same as in form editing)

```
                                if ($(e.target).is('.FormElement')) {
                                    var form = $(e.target).closest('form.FormGrid');
                                    console.log("form"+form);
                                    $("select#smallCategoryZone.FormElement", form[0]).html(selectHtml);
                                } else {
                                    //var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                    //var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                    var rowId = jQuery("#AdminCheckJqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                                    jQuery("select#" + rowId + "_smallCategoryZone").html(selectHtml);
                                }
```

Comment: Hello, it is a good idea to share how you have solved the problem.

Comment: I'am sorry for the late reply. I wrote it on top.